# How save data using Tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm trying to develop a little application on a Samsung watch (wearable 4.0). The idea is very easy, people have to answer a question each time they open the application.
Here is the basic html code:

```
<html>

<style>
h1 {color: white; font-family: courier new; font-size:150%; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 14%}
body {background-color: SkyBlue;}
#button1 {font-size: 20px; color:white; position:absolute; top: 30%; left: 23%; width: 200px; height: 55px; background-color: black; border-color: black;}
#button2 {font-size: 20px; color:white; position:absolute; top: 70%; left: 23%; width: 200px; height: 55px; background-color: black; border-color: black;}
</style>

<body>
<h1>Es tu concentré <br> sur un élément extérieur?</h1>
<button id="button1" onclick="location.href = 'Third.html';">Mon attention est captée</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="location.href = 'Third.html';">Rien ne capte mon attention</button> 

</body>

</html>
```

In the body, I put a script where events (clicking a specific button) are recorded in an array:

```
var data = [];

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    date = new Date();
    data.push("Concentré");
    data.push(date);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
    });

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    date = new Date();
    data.push("Pas Concentré");
    data.push(date);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = data;
    });
```

Finally, I would like to save the variable "data" in a txt file, so I copy/waste what I found in the Tizen documentation:

```
var documentsDir; 
documentsDir.createFile("MWRecord.txt");
function onsuccess(files) {
  var testFile = documentsDir.createFile("test.txt");
  if (testFile != null) {
     testFile.openStream("w", function(fs) {
         fs.write(data);
         fs.close();
       });
   }
 };

 function onerror(error) {
   console.log("The error " + error.message + " occurred when listing the files in the selected folder");
 };
 
 tizen.filesystem.resolve(
   'documents',
   function(dir) {
     documentsDir = dir;
     dir.listFiles(onsuccess, onerror);
   });
```

However, when trying it with the emulator, no file is created. Does someone know how I could create a file saving the events recorded?

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Hugues

Answer (score 1):

did you set the privileges?
If not, you have to set the

`mediastorage`

and the

`externalstorage`

privileges, in order that the app saves files.

Answer (score 1):

First problem that I can notice, is that your code uses 'undefined' as an object on the second line, which causes breaking of code execution.

```js
var documentsDir; 
documentsDir.createFile("MWRecord.txt");  /// documentsDir === undefined
```

Secondly, I am not sure if you need to call *listFiles()* or it is a copy paste issue, in your description I didn't find answer if it was intentional.

To create new file and fill it with some data, you need to properly handle all asynchronous operations using callbacks:

```js
tizen.filesystem.resolve(
    'documents',
    function (dir) {
        try {
            var testFile = dir.createFile("test.txt");
            testFile.openStream("w", function (fs) {
                fs.write("some data as a string");
                fs.close();
                // at this point your file is created and content is written
                console.log("Success")
            },
                function (e) {
                    // TODO handle openStream() errors here
                    console.log("openStream error occurrred " + JSON.stringify(e));
                });
        } catch (e) {
            // TODO handle createFile() errors here
            console.log("createFile error occurrred " + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    },
    function (e) {
        // TODO handle resolve() errors here
        console.log("resolve error occurrred " + JSON.stringify(e));
    });
```